# How to stop url() images from being cropped when resizing window?

Tags: html, css

I'm testing out the [following game](https://scinana.github.io/memory-card-game/) (repo [here](https://github.com/scinana/memory-card-game)) which has been set to the following css properties:

```
.game {
    min-width:400px;
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The game app has 16 divs with class=container, and inside each of these there is a div class=card that has 2 figures (one with a class = "front" and one with class = "back") - see screenshot from Chrome Inspector tools below

[image]

The class=front parts of the cards have been given an image each, defined by the following url() code example in the css file

```
[data-card-type="B2"] .front {
    background: #f5f5f5 url('../img/img4.jpg');
}
```

When resizing the whole window where my game is, I can see that the div containers also get resized, affecting the content inside them. This causes the images to get cropped so that only a portion of them shows:

[image]

Only when the div containers are at their full size, the images inside them are able to show fully.

[image]

I've tried to modify lots of different css variables (eg. setting a min width for the div containers, or for the front class) to stop the images from being "cropped", see below example for the class:

```
.front {
    background-color: #ffb3b3;
    min-width:100%
}
```

but none of these changes have worked.

Where exactly do I need to modify the code so the images stop cropping, and always show a responsive resizing (eg. get smaller or bigger but always show the whole image content)?

Comment: How about applying width: XXpx and height: XXpx to the parent div and width: 100% and height: 100% to the img?

Comment: thanks @Ajay that's a good suggestion, but if I give a static size to my divs, then they won't resize to different screens. I want to keep them resizing so users in a mobile don't have to scroll loads to see all images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the aspect ratio is right, I think you could use `background-size: contain;` in the figure css

Comment: Hey @filo thanks for your answer, but could you explain more please? Don't understand in which class to add that?

Comment: Hi @Scinana you have to insert it in the same class where you put the image style (`background: #f5f5f5 url('../img/img4.jpg');`). In your case in the `[data-card-type="B2"] .front` class

Comment: This is amazing, it worked! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Scinana Awesome!